# How to apply a function or command to every row of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, row

I have a list of items in a string with 2 columns and dozens of rows. I want to filter out every item from one of the columns. I think I can do this by applying the .split command on each row but if there's any better way to do this that doesn't involve regex I'd like to know.

Edit: I'm trying to do this with a list of names like:

```
"""Roy      Theresa     
Vincent     Diana   
Ralph       Natalie     
Eugene      Brittany""" etc.
```

When I use:

```
head, sep, tail = nameList.partition(' ')
print(head)
```

It only returns the first name in the list. I want to apply that code to every line of the string so I can get the first name off every line instead of just the first one in the whole list.

Comment: Can you post sample input and code?

Comment: Split the *string* you have into separate lines using the [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method and then partition each line.

Comment: 'Benjamin \tSamantha \t', 'Samuel \t \tKatherine \t', 'Gregory \tChristine \t', What's with all the /ts? I didn't use keepends but those still appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a direct list like:

```py
a = ["Roy Theresa","Vincent Diana","Ralph Natalie","Eugene Brittany"]
```

then all you have to do is :

```
for i in a:
    print(i.split(" ")[0])
```

to get the first world from each element of the list.

But if you have a String like :

```
b = """Roy      Theresa     
Vincent     Diana   
Ralph       Natalie     
Eugene      Brittany"""
```

First you must divide it into different names using splitlines() and repeat the
top step once you get a list of names, like this:

```
new_list = b.splitlines()
for i in new_list:
    print(i.split(" ")[0])
```

Your output will be:

```
Roy
Vincent
Ralph
Eugene
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Though could you please tell me what me what that [0] does? Changing it to another number turns up some weird results. And what part of this code would I have to change to the other column of names? Getting the ones after the space, instead of before the space.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, When you use split, it divides the line, in this case for example, "Roy     Theresa   " into ["Roy", " "," ","Theresa"," "," "] something like this. This is due to the argument we are giving inside split command - " ", whitespace inbetween the quotes to tell it to split around whitespaces, due to large number of white spaces in each line, the results list contains many whitespace elements. Try print(i.split(" ")) , without [0] to see the full list. we are giving [0] to take the first element in the list.